# Getting page id from a multidimensional array which isn't static

Tags: php, arrays, silverstripe-4

I am trying to obtain the value of the ID key from $arr without specifying which nested array its from. so returning ID from all nested arrays within $arr.

```
$arr =array(
array(
        'title' => 'home',
        'ID' => '45'
    ),

array(
        'title' => 'articleholder',
        'ID' => '25'
    ),

array(
        'title' => 'article page',
        'ID' => '23'
    )

$arr = SiteTree::get()->filter('ParentID', $page['ID'])->toNestedArray();
$id = 'ID'
var_dump($arr[$id]); //returns ['45, 25, 23']
```

if something like this could be defined as a function:

```
var_dump($arr[array_reverse_search_allnested($id)]
```

Sorry for any mistakes this is a small project and my introduction to php.

Actual array returned from a filtered sitetree:

```
    array(0) {} array(0) {} array(0) {} array(0) {} array(0) {} array(0) {} array(0) {} array(0) {} array(0) {} array(1) {
    [
        0
    ]=> array(16) {
        [
            "ClassName"
        ]=> string(4) "Page" [
            "LastEdited"
        ]=> string(19) "2019-01-08 03:58:54" [
            "Created"
        ]=> string(19) "2019-01-08 03:58:43" [
            "CanViewType"
        ]=> string(7) "Inherit" [
            "CanEditType"
        ]=> string(7) "Inherit" [
            "Version"
        ]=> string(1) "3" [
            "URLSegment"
        ]=> string(7) "level-2" [
            "Title"
        ]=> string(7) "Level 2" [
            "ShowInMenus"
        ]=> string(1) "1" [
            "ShowInSearch"
        ]=> string(1) "1" [
            "Sort"
        ]=> string(1) "1" [
            "HasBrokenFile"
        ]=> string(1) "0" [
            "HasBrokenLink"
        ]=> string(1) "0" [
            "ParentID"
        ]=> string(2) "23" [
            "ID"
        ]=> int(24) [
            "RecordClassName"
        ]=> string(4) "Page"
    }
}
```

Comment: I read your question twice.  I don't understand.  Can you give some context? What is your expected result from input? How much can your input array vary? Do you need a recursive process?

Comment: I am trying to get id, parentid, and list of children for each page on a site so I can use the information to make a visual sitetree. unfortunately as silverstripe sitetree::get doesn't return each page's children I have to search the site tree for any pages which match a certain parent id then obtain that pages id.

Comment: Please provide more realistic input data and your expected result.

Comment: I agree with @mickmackusa, the question is a bit unclear. Keep in mind to your next question to include a input and a expected result and preferably what you have tried. Basically, " I have this array .... And I want this output .... I have tried with this code .... But didn't get the expected result, what did I do wrong?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for array_column which extracts one column from a multidimensional array.

```
$id = array_column($arr, "ID");
var_dump($id);
```

Returns:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "45"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "25"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "23"
}
```

Or you can use the third argument as ID and get the following output:

```
$id = array_column($arr, "title","ID");
var_dump($id);

/*array(3) {
  [45]=>
  string(4) "home"
  [25]=>
  string(13) "articleholder"
  [23]=>
  string(12) "article page"
}*/
```

Comment: I thought that too.  The sample input may be misleading.  I'd like to know if the input might have deeper levels.

Comment: Thank you I should have further investigated array column, I was just to sure array_search would have a parameter or use case to search nested.